# Show button if div length is higher than one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I do show/hide (toggle) a button element if `div#choices` has more than one div inside it and each time the `div#choices` is showed (it's hidden by default)? This is the code where I toggle `div#choices`:

```
$('#choices').on("change", ":checkbox", function(e) {
    var theName = $(this).attr('name');
    var theID = $(this).attr('value');
    var input = "";

    input = '<span>' + capitalize(theName) + '<input name="input_' + theName + '[]" data-id="' + theName + '_' + theID + '" value="" placeholder="' + capitalize(theName) + '" /><br/></span>';

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':button').before(input);
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).show();
    } else {
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':not(button)').remove();
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).hide();
    }
});
```

**Update: added jsFiddle and working on some code based on suggestions**

Here is the example of code in which I'm working on: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5bfJ/4/)

Also this is the code I made but without success since button remains even when children div's are hidden:

```
function toggleCreateVariationButton() {
    var toggleThis = $("#choices").children('div').length > 1 && $('#choices').children('div').css('display') != "none" ? true : false;
    $("button#create-variation").toggle(toggleThis);
}
```

I call the function any time I clone a input, what's wrong?

Comment: Just a tip, reading about jquery chaining

Comment: @Itay how is supposed that jQuery chaining will help me on this?

Comment: whenever you want something as exact as this, always jsfiddle it.

Comment: It's not the solution for your problem but it'll make your code light and more efficient

Comment: @Itay okey I'll take into account, right now as you may see my jQuery isn't advanced

Comment: @Overcode re-read the main post, I added the code I'm working on and also the jsFiddle as you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check how many child elements are inside another element with `$(el).children().length` in your case `$('#choices').children().length`

You can also check the current CSS value for the `display` or `visibility` property to see if the element is currently visible $('#choices').css('display')

Hope that helps

Comment: Can you take a look at my code to see what I'm doing wrong since it's not working?

Comment: Sure there are more elegant solutions but have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/wp7ZV/2/ I've changed slightly your HTML and rewrote the JS

Comment: isn't your code attached to the elements on the jsFiddle I leave here? Shouldn't since elements are created on the fly depending on DB selection :-( so yes your code look nice but wont work for me, could you please remove the dependency for this `var talla = $('<div><span>Talla<input name="input_talla[]" data-id="talla_24" value="" placeholder="Talla"></span><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');` and this `var colour = $('<div><span>Colour ....');` in order to work with dynamic elements as I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can put the dummy elements in your HTML. Something like <div id="dummies">`<div class="talla">...</div><div class="colour">...</div></div>` and `clone()` the relevant one. See [link](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)